# addView for GridView

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I want to add a footer view for GridView.

I find in the documentation GridView has 2 inherited **addView(View child)** method.

```
From class android.widgetAdapterView

void addView(View child)

This method is not supported and throws an UnsupportedOperationException when called.
```

and

```
From class android.view.ViewGroup

void addView(View child)

Adds a child view.
```

It seems I should use the latter. But how can I call this particular inherited method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. It overwrites the original with a `UnsupportedOperationException` because it's.. well.. not supported.

You should be editing the adapter instead. Depending on your implementation, this will look different. But, you just have to add more data to the adapter, and call `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, and your `GridView` will add the view by itself.

A footer view should either be a separate `View` after your `GridView`, or you will have to maintain its position in the adapter's list to always be last whenever you add new items.

Comment: adding it to the adapter seems cool. But the footview will sure be wider than other items in the gridview. any way to handle this?

Comment: You will have to use a custom adapter, in that case. Then check, if `position == items.length - 1`, then inflate a wider `View`.

Comment: I mean the foot view should occupy a single row. While other rows have  3 items. How can this be done?

Comment: I see. You may have to use a view outside the `GridView`, then. `GridView` does not support spanning.

Comment: @Eric have you found some solution for your problem? I need to add a one column header " Logged in as xy" and below will be a gridview but the first one has to be scrollable as the gridview.

Comment: @CicPot Yes, as I said in the post you have to use the adapter to inflate a separate view which remains at the start of your list of items. You can use a custom adapter to have a different view for the header and view items.

Comment: @Eric thanks for the reply! Inside the custom adapter my getView() returns two types of Views (header and the other) - but what the problem is how did you solve the columns problem considering the header. My gridview has 2 columns - so I thought about inflating the header view at position 1 and inflating an empty view type only for the position 2 ....all the other positions would be the images (gridview) below the header. How did you solve this?

Comment: @CicPot That's probably what I'd do as well; it's been a while since I posted this answer. Did you try it out?

Comment: @Eric Well I will try that because I do not have that much options...my only other option would be to use some stickyheadergridview library ...but I am not sure whether it is stable etc..so I will go this way. Thanks anyway for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Providing an example of Erics solution, the adapter could maintain two extra members for tracking the
position of the "footer", and its event handler:

```
class ImageViewGridAdapter : ArrayAdapter<int>
{
    private readonly List<int> images;

    public int EventHandlerPosition { get; set; }
    public EventHandler AddNewImageEventHandler { get; set; }

    public ImageViewGridAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<int> images)
        : base(context, textViewResourceId, images)
    {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView v = (ImageView)convertView;

        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            v = (ImageView)li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GridItem_Image, null);

            // ** Need to assign event handler in here, since GetView 
            // is called an arbitrary # of times, and the += incrementor
            // will result in multiple event fires

            // Technique 1 - More flexisble, more maintenance ////////////////////
            if (position == EventHandlerPosition)            
                v.Click += AddNewImageEventHandler;

            // Technique 2 - less flexible, less maintenance /////////////////////
            if (position == images.Count)
                v.Click += AddNewImageEventHandler;
        }

        if (images[position] != null)
        {
            v.SetBackgroundResource(images[position]);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Then, before assigning the adapter to the grid view, just assign those values (position doesn't have to be at end, but for a footer it should be):

```
List<int> images = new List<int> { 
    Resource.Drawable.image1, Resource.Drawable.image2, Resource.Drawable.image_footer 
};

ImageViewGridAdapter recordAttachmentsAdapter = new ImageViewGridAdapter(Activity, 0, images);

recordAttachmentsAdapter.EventHandlerPosition = images.Count;
recordAttachmentsAdapter.AddNewImageEventHandler += NewAttachmentClickHandler;

_recordAttachmentsGrid.Adapter = recordAttachmentsAdapter;
```